# Nested for loop of an object in Vue

Tags: vue.js, object, nuxt.js

I have an object and I'd like to make a menu of it.
Here is what I have, the parent ol works, but the second one, the child doesn't because I don't know how. So first I list up the chapters, and then I want to list the sections of that current chapter. Pretty straight forward if you look at the object I guess. Who can help?

```
<template>
    <ol>
    <li
            v-for="({ path, label, chapter }) in $ROUTES.chapters"
            :key="label"
        >
            <nuxt-link
                :to="localePath($ROUTES.home)"
            >
                {{ label }}
            </nuxt-link>

            <ol>
                <li
                    :key="chapter.sections.label"
                >
                    <nuxt-link
                        :to="localePath(chapter.sections.path)"
                    >
                        {{ chapter.sections.label }}
                    </nuxt-link>
                </li>
            </ol>
    </li>
    </ol>
</template>
```

```
export const ROUTES = Object.freeze({
    home: "/",
    chapters: {
        chapter1:
        {
            path: "/1-introduction",
            label: "1 Introduction",
            sections: {
                section1: {
                    path: "1.1-all-about-batteries",
                    label: "1.1 All about batteries",
                },
                section2: {
                    path: "1.2-why-recycle",
                    label: "1.2 Why recycle",
                },
                section3: {
                    path: "1.3-ultimate-goal",
                    label: "1.3 Ultimate goal",
                },
            },
        },
        chapter2:
        {
            path: "/2-collecting-and-sorting",
            label: "2 Collecting and sorting",
            sections: {
                section1: {
                    path: "2.1-storing-batteries-at-home",
                    label: "2.1 Storing batteries at home",
                },
                section2: {
                    path: "2.2-bebat-collection-system",
                    label: "2.2 Bebat collection system",
                },
                section3: {
                    path: "2.3-sortbat-sorting-system",
                    label: "2.3 Sortbat sorting system",
                },
            },
        },
        chapter3:
        {
            path: "/3-recycling",
            label: "3 Recycling",
            sections: {
                section1: {
                    path: "3.1-battery-recycling-history",
                    label: "3.1 Battery recycling history",
                },
                section2: {
                    path: "3.2-modern-trends",
                    label: "3.2 Modern trends",
                },
                section3: {
                    path: "3.3-general-recycle-process",
                    label: "3.3 General recycle process",
                },
            },
        },
        chapter4:
        {
            path: "/4-faq",
            label: "4 FAQ",
            sections: {
                section1: {
                    path: "4.1-frequently-asked-questions",
                    label: "4.1 Frequently asked questions",
                },
            },
        },
        chapter5:
        {
            path: "/5-future",
            label: "5 Future",
            sections: {
                section1: {
                    path: "5.1-safety-concerns",
                    label: "5.1 Safety Concerns",
                },
                section2: {
                    path: "5.2-the-future",
                    label: "5.2 The future",
                },
                section3: {
                    path: "5.3-a-message-from-bebat",
                    label: "5.3 A message from Bebat",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your chapters object to an array and I would also change the nested sections object to an array for example your chapters object would look like this

```js
chapters: [
        {
            path: "/1-introduction",
            label: "1 Introduction",
            sections: [
                 {
                    path: "1.1-all-about-batteries",
                    label: "1.1 All about batteries",
                },
                {
                    path: "1.2-why-recycle",
                    label: "1.2 Why recycle",
                },
                 {
                    path: "1.3-ultimate-goal",
                    label: "1.3 Ultimate goal",
                },
            ]
        ]
```

You would obviously continue to add all the chapters to the array. And then your template would look like this

```html
<template>
    <ol>
    <li
            v-for="chapter in $ROUTES.chapters"
            :key="chapter.label"
        >
            <nuxt-link
                :to="localePath($ROUTES.home)"
            >
                {{ chapter.label }}
            </nuxt-link>

            <ol>
                <li
                    v-for="section in chapter.section"
                    :key="section.label"
                >
                    <nuxt-link
                        :to="localePath(section.path)"
                    >
                        {{section.label }}
                    </nuxt-link>
                </li>
            </ol>
    </li>
    </ol>
</template>
```

Note the nested v-for loop that will go over your sections array for every chapter that you have. So to summarize I would change your objects to arrays and then do a nested v-for loop for your sections in the chapter

Comment: @Aaron Angle Okay, but why change the object? And :to="localePath($ROUTES.home)" can't be in a template because it's only used once. This has to be $ROUTES.label I presume. This doesn't work, too bad.

Comment: This is the solution :) Thanks, but I preferred my object though..
`
 <ol>
    <li
   v-for="chapter in $ROUTES.chapters"
   :key="chapter.label"
    >
   <nuxt-link
    :to="localePath($ROUTES.home)"
   >
    {{ chapter.label }}
   </nuxt-link>

   <ol>
    <li
     v-for="section in chapter.sections"
     :key="section.label"
    >
     <nuxt-link
      :to="localePath(section.path)"
     >
      {{ section.label }}
     </nuxt-link>
    </li>
   </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
`

Comment: If you're going to use a v-for I'm pretty sure you need to use an array with objects instead of just an object. I'm sure there's a way to do it keeping your object the same but this is the way I would do it